# can prime sense sensor detect two people hugging or back-to-back closely?

Tags: openni

I try to detect two people hugging or back-to-back closely by prime sense sensor. Currently I can track two people simultaneously and their skeleton data when they stand at a distance. but if they are hugging or back-to-back closely, their skeleton will be merged into one. can anyone tell me what should i do to detect the actions(hug/backToback) between two people?

Platform: windows 7
OpenNI version: 1.5.7
NITE version: 1.5.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the OpenNI scene segmentation alone will do, since as you observed yourself, having 2 people close to each other will cause the outlines to merge.

You would need to run your own algorithm around this merging issue yourself.
There are probably a few different ways to tackle this.

Here are a few hacky ideas that to mind at the moment:

**Idea #1**

Use OpenNI's scene segmentation feature and analyze the user pixels even though they are merged. If you analyze the outline. By looking at the distance between the edges(outer most pixels) and the centroid, you should spot extremities (largest distances), which would be hand/feet and the head. If your blob has two heads probably it's two people hugging.

**Idea #2**

You know that when users get closer they merge into a single user which means new user/lost user event triggers from OpenNI. On top of this you can keep track of each user's CoM(centre of mass, available in OpenNI). If the distance between the two users decreases a lot and this is immediately followed by a new user event (the merged blob), which has a bigger bounding box than each of the two users, then it's likely you're users are hugging or very close to each other.

**Idea #3**

You can track the upper body skeleton profile only for each user and detect a "hug" gesture. You can start with an initial crude pose detection where the angle of the arms is within certain threshold values. Instead of detecting pose, you could use [DTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) to detect a gesture. If at least one of the two users triggers this pose/gesture prior to OpenNI detecting 'fused' users then you might detect a hug.

**Idea #4**

Using some of the ideas above: the fact that the merged blob will be larger than either of the members and will be detect after the number of users decreases, you can use a hug detecting haar cascade on the rgb pixels belonging to the newly detected merged blob to confirm the hug.

Some of these ideas will be easier to implement than others, but it's important to keep out false positive of. Ideally you would have a simple scene (no complex objects in the background) with decent lighting( artificial cold, preferably anything away from the infrared range (sunlight, incandescent light, etc.)) to make your life easier. I've observed that with complex background sometimes even a single user can get merged with a background object.